# Need to display hosted html page in full screen on page load

Tags: java, javascript, gwt

I am developing a GWT web application and for a specific requirement I need to display my only hosted html page in full screen on load.
This we done with the help of pressing F11 on any web page. I need exactly the same functionality in my GWT application.

I have tried glimpses of Javascript for this which wasn't worked.

```
<script language="JavaScript1.2">
    top.window.moveTo(0,0);
    if (document.all) {
        top.window.resizeTo(screen.availWidth,screen.availHeight);
    }
    else if (document.layers||document.getElementById) 
    {
        if   (top.window.outerHeight<screen.availHeight||top.window.outerWidth<screen.availWidth){
    top.window.outerHeight = screen.availHeight;
    top.window.outerWidth = screen.availWidth;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Could it be possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't force the user on how to display your document. Still, there's a [Draft for a fullscreen api](http://dvcs.w3.org/hg/fullscreen/raw-file/tip/Overview.html), see also https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Using_full-screen_mode

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need to use the page you load to launch a new browser window with the fullpage html in it.  The first page is nothing but to kick off the full page with a script like this

```
<script>
<!--
window.open("fullpage.html","fs","fullscreen=yes")
//-->
</script>
```

Comment: This can't be done in the case of my GWT application as I am using only on hosted html page.
I need a functionality same as when you press F11 on browser and it changes to fullscreen.

Comment: Most browsers intentionally prevent the behavior you want.  They let the user choose the browser size.  The best you can hope for is a browser opened from within your hosted page.